# Linear map such that $\ker f \cap \operatorname{im} f = \{0\}$. Show that $V = \ker f \oplus \operatorname{im} f$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space and $f \colon V\to V$ be a linear map such that $\ker f \cap \operatorname{im} f = \{0\}$. Show that $V = \ker f \oplus \operatorname{im} f$.

I have that $\{v \in V \mid f(v) =0 \} \cap \{f(v) \mid v\in V\}= \{0\}$. If I understand this correctly it means that there's no such element that $f(v) = 0$ and is in the image of $f$? From the problem statement it seems that this would somehow imply that $V$ is the sum of these two sets?

Comment: Do you know the rank-nullity theorem?

Comment: Since right-shift $\bigoplus_{n ∈ ℕ} F → \bigoplus_{n ∈ ℕ} F,~(x_1, x_2, …) ↦ (0, x_1,  x_2, …)$ would be a counterexample, you really need to invest the finite dimensionality somehow.

Answer (score 1):

$\ker \ f , \operatorname{im} \ f \subset V$ subspace of $V$. $\ker \ f \cap \operatorname{im} \ f=\{0_v\}$ then there is no non zero element $x$ in $V$ that $x$ in $\ker f$ and $\operatorname{im} f$. So we can say $\ker f \oplus \operatorname{im} f$ exists Let $\dim V=n$  $$\dim V=\dim{ (\ker \ f)} +\dim{ (\operatorname{im} \ f) }-\dim( \ker \ f \cap \ \operatorname{im} \ f) $$ Also $\dim ( \ \ker \ f \cap \ \operatorname{im}\ f) =\dim\{ 0_v \}=0$ so $\dim V= \dim( {\ \ker \ f}) + \dim( { \ \operatorname{im} \ f })$ we can get $V=\ker \ f \oplus \operatorname{im} \ f$